# How to have background color in CSS if image is not a certain size?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

div.nyc {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1.5px;
}

.myimage {
  width: 248px;
  height: 186px;
}

.myimage {
  background-color:#E7E82;
}
```

```html
<h2>Used Cars for Cash in Queens, NY</h2>
<div class="nyc">
  <img class="myimage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/1989_Honda_Civic_GL_sedan_%2824990238761%29.jpg/1024px-1989_Honda_Civic_GL_sedan_%2824990238761%29.jpg" alt="">
  <h3>Honda Civic 1.4 GL</h3>
  <p>1989. Crystal green, this sedan is an import from Australia over 25 years old! $2,500</p>
  <img class="myimage" src="https://i.imgur.com/lOhCCzD.jpg" alt="">
  <h3>Burstner A Class</h3>
  <p>More info... due soon! POA</p>
</div>
```

How can I with CSS make it so images of a certain width - ie. images not 248px wide 186px high get the background but images under that width do get the color?

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: *images under that width do get the color?* --> what you mean by *get the color* ?

Comment: Probably only with javascript but yah, clarification will help us to understand better.

Comment: You want to replace images that don't match the w/h criteria with some background-color?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question probably, then you might want something like this,

```html
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  div.nyc {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1.5px;
  }
  
  .myimage {
    width: 248px;
    height: 186px;
  }
  
  .myimage {
    background-color: red;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
</style>

<H2>Used Cars for Cash in Queens, NY</H2>

<div class="nyc">
  <img class="myimage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/1989_Honda_Civic_GL_sedan_%2824990238761%29.jpg/1024px-1989_Honda_Civic_GL_sedan_%2824990238761%29.jpg">
  <h3>Honda Civic 1.4 GL</h3>
  <p>1989. Crystal green, this sedan is an import from Australia over 25 years old! $2,500</p>
  <img class="myimage" src="https://i.imgur.com/lOhCCzD.jpg">
  <h3>Burstner A Class</h3>
  <p>More info... due soon! POA</p>
</div>
```